# How to make console.log command while gatsby service (node) is running

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I playing around with gatsby (static site generator).
I created an `.env` file and install the required `dotenv` package.

In the config file I put this code:

```
require("dotenv").config({path:`.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,})
```

How is it possible to test the `env` variables in the console with `console.log` while `gatsby develop` is loaded in the frontend?

I work on a windows system in visual studio code and PowerShell command line. Although I set the `ENV_NODE` Parameter in the environment variables of windows

The `console.log` commands directly in the config file or in the frontend files (like `index.js`) works. But it's strange because the variables without `GATSBY` (as written in the documentation) works in the frontend.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

To access the environment variables directly in your browser, you should prefix them with `GATSBY_` as [their documentation about environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) explains:

> In Node, your site has access to your `API_KEY` (Server-side) using the
> identifier `process.env.API_KEY`. To access it client-side, you can use
> a `.env.*` file containing `API_KEY`. However, you are **strongly** advised
> against checking these files into source control as it’s a security
> issue to expose the API key. As a more secure alternative, you can
> prefix your variable with `GATSBY_` (as shown above). With this prefix,
> Gatsby automatically embeds the variable as `process.env.GATSBY\_\`* in
> compiled JS making it available in the browser context without
> exposing it elsewhere.

Unprefixed variables inside `console.logs()` placed in the files that run while the compilation occurs (`gatsby-config.js`, etc) are not displayed in the browser's console since those `console.logs` runs in the server (your local machine). If you place a `console.log` there, it will be visible in the terminal (VSCode terminal, Powershell terminal, etc) but not in the browser. They are server-side variables.

Since `NODE_ENV` is a reserved environment variable, you can't prefix them so you won't be able to show it in the browser's console. Extending, [their documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#reserved-environment-variables):

> You can not override certain environment variables as some are used
> internally for optimizations during build, such as:
>
> - `NODE_ENV`
> - `PUBLIC_DIR`

Summarizing, to test variables in your client-side (for example `index.js`) you need to prefix them with `GATSBY_` and print them in the console if you want. It may work under `develop` but it may cause severe issues in a `build` mode if don't. The output for the server-side will be the terminal, not the browser's console.

Files executed during the compilation in the server-side (`gatsby-config.js`, etc) will also output in the terminal rather than the browser's console. The opposite of the client-side variables, which will output in the browser's console. It's a matter of who renders the variables, the server, or the client.